# How to convert <table><tr>...</tr></table> into a HashMap (Java)?

Tags: java

Ok, I have a String that has `<table>` structure like this:

```
String tableTags="<table> "+
                    "<tr>" +
                          "<td> val1 </td>" +
                          "<td> val2 </td>" +
                    "</tr>" +

                    "<tr>" +
                          "<td> val3 </td>" +
                          "<td> val4 </td>" +
                    "</tr>" +
                 "</table>";
```

I want to convert `String tableTags` into a `HasHMap<String, List<String>>`. Each key of `HashMap` is a **table row** & `List<String>` of each key will contain all values of that row.

Note: the number of rows and columns of a table is unknown. Also it is a complete table (ie there is no empty cell).

Or can you find a better way or easier to do that? You don't need to use `HashMap` you can use `String[][]`?

Comment: You need to *parse* that string to extract the data.

Comment: Do you have same number of columns for each row?

Comment: What will be key in case of HashMap?

Comment: just row no can be the key

Comment: yes, it has the same number of cols for each row. it' a complete table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it ok.

```
public static String[][] convertTableHtmlTagsTo2DArray(String tableHtmlTags){

    String[] allRows=tableHtmlTags.split("</tr>");

    if(allRows!=null && allRows.length>0){
        int noOfRow=allRows.length;
        String[] allElementsInFirstRow=allRows[0].split("</td>");
        int noOfCol=allElementsInFirstRow.length;
        String[][] tableHtmlTagsIn2DArray=new String[noOfRow][noOfCol];

        for(int r=0; r<allRows.length; r++){
            String eachRow = allRows[r];
            String[] allElementsInEachRow=allRows[r].split("</td>");
            for(int e=0; e<allElementsInEachRow.length; e++){
                String eachElement=allElementsInEachRow[e];

                eachElement=MyValidation.cleanString(eachElement); // if it is null it will turn to "";

                eachElement=eachElement.replaceAll(".*<td>", "");
                eachElement=MyValidation.cleanString(eachElement);
                tableHtmlTagsIn2DArray[r][e]=eachElement;
            }
        }
        return tableHtmlTagsIn2DArray;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Parse the string into rows and cells. You can either find a library to do this or, if that would be overkill, roll your own with string operations.
2. Come up with some representation of a row. As you've specified in the question, you want the key to be a `String`. There's not much detail in the question about this, so you probably had your own plans on what this should be.
3. Add the rows and cell contents to a `HashMap` in the way you've already described.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to parse all the `<td>` values:

Now it depends on you that where you want to store it. I have stored it in `List` as well as `String[][]`.

```
String tableTags = "<table> " + "<tr>" + "<td> val1 </td>" + "<td> val2 </td>" + "</tr>"
        + "<tr>" + "<td> val3 </td>" + "<td> val4 </td>" + "</tr>" + "</table>";

int fromIndex = 0;
int toIndex = 0;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (true) {
    fromIndex = tableTags.indexOf("<td>", fromIndex);
    if (fromIndex == -1) {
        break;
    } else {
        toIndex = tableTags.indexOf("</td>", fromIndex);
        if (toIndex == -1) {
            break;
        }
        list.add(tableTags.substring(fromIndex + 4, toIndex).trim());
        fromIndex = toIndex;
    }
}

int tdsPerRow = 2;

String[][] array = new String[list.size() / tdsPerRow][tdsPerRow];
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
for (String str : list) {
    if (col == tdsPerRow) {
        row++;
        col = 0;
    }
    array[row][col] = str;
    col++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(array[i][0] + "-" + array[i][1]);
}
```

Comment: The no Of rows is unknown, but Thank you very much anyway, I provided my answer